# Ionic structure same as Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, code-structure

I know a little bit about Angularjs (I'm still learning) and now I want to learn Ionic too. I tried to have same structure approach for code organization, but it seems that I don't know how to make same code works on Ionic. Can someone helps me, I will write my code first and then explain what is the problem.

index

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter">

    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>

    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="app/application.js"></script>
    <script src="app/controllers/userDataCtr.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

app

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])

    .run(function($ionicPlatform) {
        $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
            if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
                cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
                cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
            }
            if(window.StatusBar) {
                StatusBar.styleDefault();
            }
        });
    })

.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider

        .state('home', {
            url: '/home',
            controller: 'userDataCtr',
            templateUrl: 'app/views/home.html'
        })

    ;

    // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
});
```

controller

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('starter')
        .controller('userDataCtr', userDataCtr);

    userDataCtr.$inject=['$state','$window'];

    function userDataCtr($state,$window) {

        var vm = this;

        vm.test = test;

        function test() {
            vm.testing = "Does work?";
        }
    }
})();
```

home view

```
<div ng-init="userDataCtr.test()">{{testing}}</div>
```

When I start application I get nothing on screen, blank page. It seems like function is not even started. Does anyone know where I'm wrong?

Thanks

Edit:

Now I figure out that if I change this:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('starter')
        .controller('userDataCtr', userDataCtr);

    userDataCtr.$inject=['$state','$window'];

    function userDataCtr($state,$window) {

        var vm = this;

        vm.test = test;

        function test() {
            vm.testing = "Does work?";
        }
    }
})();
```

to this:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('starter')
        .controller('userDataCtr', userDataCtr);

    userDataCtr.$inject=['$state','$window','$scope'];

    function userDataCtr($state,$window,$scope) {

        $scope.test - function() {
            $scope.testing = "Does work?";
        }
    }
})();
```

Works !!

But I don't want to use $scope. Does anyone knows why first solution fail and another works?

Comment: Because in the first case, `userDataCtr` is not in the scope, and the expression `userDataCtr.test()` thus does nothing. That has nothing to do with ionic. You need `controllerAs` to put the controller in the scope and use it from the view. http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$stateProvider#methods_state

Comment: Thanks a lot, works